# All windows dissapeared from STS after opening tag registry

Tags: eclipse, ide

It seems that all my window panes in workbench became irresponsible in STS when tried *Window->Show view->Other->Tag registry*.
Then after restart all panes become invisible/dissapeared.

I use Spring Tool Suite:

Version: 3.9.6.RELEASE
Build Id: 201809180749
Platform: Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0)

[image]

Clicking on the icons of the toolbar visible on the right side only hides window visible on the left. Panels/windows don't come back after restarting IDE.

Comment: You can try resetting the Perspective from the Window menu in the menu bar.

Comment: Thank you, it seems resetting perspective, closing STS and starting again helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to reset the Perspective from the Window menu.